# Error \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than > \pdfstartlink

Tags: errors, pdftex, nesting

When compiling this tex file in ShareLaTeX, I get the following error:

> Error in English1213/LaTeX_English_def.tex (line 96): pdfTeX error
>   (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than
>   \pdfstartlink. \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
>                                                     \fi \fi  l.96 \end{document}

This error started occurring from the moment I placed a second \citeA{} command in my text. When I compile it with only 1 `\citeA{}` command, there is no problem....

Can somebody help me with this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{StyleEN}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}

% Title.
% ------
\title{FEASIBILITY STUDY OF HEAT NETWORK IMPLEMENTATION}


% Authors
% -------
\author{Peter Vanvoorden\supit{*}\\ \vspace*{0.25cm}
            \small{\supit{*}Master student $<$Biochemical Engineering$>$, GROUP T - Leuven Engineering College, Vesaliusstraat 13, 3000 Leuven \\ \vspace*{1.5cm}
            Supervisor(s): $<$Koen Pelsmaekers$>$ \\            
            Unit $<$Informatietechnologie$>$, GROUP T - Leuven Engineering College, Vesaliusstraat 13, 3000 Leuven, $<$\href{mailto:koen.pelsmaekers@groept.be}{koen.pelsmaekers@groept.be}$>$} \\ \vspace*{1em}
            Co-supervisor(s): $<$Stijn De Jonge\supit{1}, Dries Haeseldonckx\supit{2}, Nicolas Dosselaere\supit{3}$>$\\
            Coöperatief Ondernemen in Rationeel Energiegebruik (CORE) cvba-so, Naamsestraat 96, 3000 Leuven - Belgium\supit{1,2}\\ Nazka Mapps bvba, Ravesteinstraat 48A, 3191 Hever - Belgium\supit{3}
            }


\begin{document}

\input{TitlePageEN.tex}

%\pagebreak
\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

Focusing on Belgium, statistics from \citeA{tradeco} point out that currently 97.51 \% of its population is living in urban areas while less than 1\% of them is connected to a DH network \cite{Euroheat1}. A study of \citeA{Santens} recapitulates the causes for this low adaptivity to three major categories: Economical, Institutional and Carbon-dioxide/Price related barriers. Within these, most emphasis is placed on following topics which could be considered potential fields of improvement: uncertainty of stable profits, non-recoverable costs in terms of existing individual and distribution infrastructure, a low priority and engagement from local governments, and the low availability of data concerning heat demand and heat supply.\\

%\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably it is caused by a link that is broken across pages. That does not work reliable. (I cannot reproduce the problem, because too many files are missing.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This has nothing to do with the problem, but the code from `\newif\ifpdf` to `\fi` should be removed, because it *doesn't* do what you expect it to, unless you're using a very old TeX distribution. If you have a recent one, `\usepackage{graphicx}` suffices. Don't load `epsfig` anyway nor use its commands, because it's an obsolete package.

Comment: Sorry, I only use ShareLaTeX to write my papers, and normally I start from scratch but for my thesis I needed to use a template from my institution. Even with all these parts deleted it still gives the same error code.

I reduced the code above % Title to this:

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{StyleEN}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}

Comment: PLease try to run without the line `\usepackage{StyleEN}`. If the problem persists, the problem is in the file `TitlePageEn.tex`. Please remove all the commented lines, the `\author` and `\title` (as not used), the citatioins (as not known to us) and all packages and definitions you don't use (`amsmath`, `\def\x`...). Btw. the `hyperref` package should be loaded last.

Comment: doing these things just kills my document... Layout is changing, number of errors ran up to 24. I really need to keep the formatting as this is obligatory. It was working before the \citeA command. How is it possible that this brings such errors?

Comment: I edited your MWE, but please try to reduce further. Leave the citations in, sorry, I overread, that you blame them for your errors.

Comment: OK, then kick out the `\input{TitlePageEN.tex}` line. Same errors? We need to see `StyleEN` then. Are you sure, you have correct citations for `tradeco` and `Santens`? Try others!

Comment: when I delete that line I get an extra error:

Error in English1213/LaTeX_English_def.tex: ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Both citations are correct, it are just 2 normal bib items, for ex:

@mastersthesis{Santens, author    = "Santens, P.", title     = "Warmtenetten in Vlaanderen: Context en barrières", school    = "Hogeschool Gent - Associatie UGent - Handelswetenschappen en Bestuurskunde", year      = "2012", url       = "http://www.positive-awards.be/IMG.pdf", note      = "[Accessed on: April 15, 2014]"}

Comment: the ; displayed in the previous comment right before ', note' is not there but I cant get rid of it in the comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13903/discussion-between-larifari-and-peter-vanvoorden)

Comment: I am logged in and go to the chat, can read your message but it constantly tells me that I need to log in again.. Sorry

Comment: Without a standalone MWE we can't really get to the bottom of this, sorry.